# Setting a random seed in Lua

Tags: random, lua

I wonder how to use `math.randomseed` in Lua. Indeed when used as a function, I get an error and when used as a variable it just does not work.

```
> math.randomseed = 0
> math.random()
0.51340090995654
> math.randomseed = 0
> math.random()
0.9522297247313
> math.randomseed (44)
stdin:1: attempt to call a number value (field 'randomseed')
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`math.randomseed()` is a function that's stored in `math` table under `randomseed` name.

After you've assigned some value to `math` table under `randomseed` name, you've lost original value that was stored there - the function that would actually set the seed. And you can't execute the number, because it is not a function.

Start with calling `math.randomseed()` as a function, and do not assign numbers there.